# Clone a Laravel project but can't run

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-8, laravel-upgrade

After cloning a project and run the command `composer install`, it shows these errors.

> Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
>
> **Problem 1**
> - cache/adapter-common is locked to version 0.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - cache/adapter-common 0.4.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> **Problem 2**
> - cache/filesystem-adapter is locked to version 0.4.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - cache/filesystem-adapter 0.4.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> **Problem 3**
> - cache/tag-interop is locked to version 1.0.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
> - cache/tag-interop 1.0.0 requires php ^5.5 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.

When I update the .env file according to the Laravel doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#php-7.3.0-required then run a command `composer update` it shows an error again

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> **Problem 1**
> - Root composer.json requires php 7.3.0. but your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> **Problem 2**
> - Root composer.json requires cache/filesystem-adapter ^0.4.0 -> satisfiable by cache/filesystem-adapter[0.4.0].
> - cache/filesystem-adapter 0.4.0 requires php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> **Problem 3**
> - Root composer.json requires doctrine/dbal 2.9.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/dbal[v2.9.2].
> - doctrine/dbal v2.9.2 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
> **Problem 4**
> - laravel/passport[v7.2.0, ..., v7.5.1] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.5] but it conflicts
> with your root composer.json require (^7.0.1).
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport ^7.2 -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v7.2.0, ..., v7.5.1].
>
> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades,
> downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific
> versions.

**How to update the composer.json for another one also plz help me.**

Comment: Have you read that error message? "Root composer.json requires php 7.3.0. but your php version (8.0.0) does not satisfy that requirement." sounds pretty clear to me

Comment: Thanks, @NicoHaase for your kind response. Problem resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this type of the same problem Just upgrade or degrade your PHP versions. Just do the following steps.

- Clone a project
- Visit [php.net](https://www.php.net/)
- Install the version according to the requirement
- Set the path of PHP: Goto properties->Advance system settings->Evironment variable->Path